# release prepare hangs at git push

Tags: git, maven, netbeans

I use NetBeans 8.0.2 with embedded Maven on Win x64. The version of the release plugin is 2.5.3. Until now I used SVN as scm and deploying runs without problems. Now I switch to git and has an issue at release:prepare.

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.248s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Nov 16 16:47:33 CET 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/273M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Checking in modified POMs...
Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git add -- pom.xml"
Working directory: C:\Data\dev\Workspace\NetBeans\myGitProj\scm_12_0004
Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status"
Working directory: C:\Data\dev\Workspace\NetBeans\myGitProj\scm_12_0004
Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git commit --verbose -F C:\Users\RD3\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-1552536175.commit pom.xml"
Working directory: C:\Data\dev\Workspace\NetBeans\myGitProj\scm_12_0004
Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git symbolic-ref HEAD"
Working directory: C:\Data\dev\Workspace\NetBeans\myGitProj\scm_12_0004
Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push https://172.16.40.5/redmine/projekte/12_0004/scm_12_0004.git master:master"
Working directory: C:\Data\dev\Workspace\NetBeans\myGitProj\scm_12_0004
```

After run the goal release:prepare the plugin hangs for ever at the push point. The access to the remote git repository is only over https possible.

Whats my mistake?

Best regards

Comment: Are you running on command line or within in NetBeans ?

Comment: at NetBeans over the context menu and then custom->goals.. item.

Comment: This is a wild guess but maybe git is hanging because it waits for you to input a passphrase but you can't do it.

Comment: You should try on command line first....

Comment: on command line with maven 3.3.3 its exact the same issue:

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. After many tests I realized the problem happened when 'git push' was executing and it couldn't authenticate due to there weren't credentials to access the GIT server.
In my case I usually work through VPN; the GIT server of my company has some credentials, my computer another credentials, and the Artifactory's server another credentials as well. So, in my case setting up the Maven release plugin GIT credentials solved my problem.

I use maven-release-plugin and SCM config on pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </plugin>


    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:http://url.gitserver.com/system/_git/project_name</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>
```

So I need to set up the following steps:

**Add a property Id to pom.xml:**

```
<properties>
   <project.scm.id>git</project.scm.id>
</properties>
```

**Add the reference of the Id to Settings.xml**

```
   <server>
      <id>git</id>  
      <username>myUser</username>  
      <password>myPassword</password>  
   </server>
```

> Another solution even simpler than the two previous steps; you can specify your credentials only to Maven settings.xml using the GIT Url address in the Id tag, such as:

```
<server>
  <id>url.gitserver.com</id>
  <username>user</username>
  <password>password</password>
</server>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `release:prepare` with some type of verbose-flag, so that it logs more information and you can analyse, where it hangs